# Is there any way to get Dark Side items besides the vendor on the fleet and random drops?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently went all the way from Light V to Dark V in order to buy the speeder and pet from the Dark Side vendor on the Fleet.  I'm planning on heading back to the light but while I'm here I figure I should take advantage of it (even if some gear won't "work" once I am no longer Dark Side).

I know Dark Side relics, sabers, etc. drop from questing and crew missions all the time, and as mentioned I've been to the DS vendor on the Fleet.  Are there any other ways to get Dark Side items?  Particularly, other vendors or anything that is less common/has additional requirements?

Comment: You can receive relics with dark/light side requirements from certain high-level crew missions.

Comment: @Mufasa I mentioned that :P

Comment: What about Galactic Trade?

Comment: @Suma Hmm yes, for sure.  Thanks for the reminder!  I think a lot of this stuff is BoP though.

Comment: Still somebody at the dark side may be able to get the equipment for you (fresh new, unbound) for a considerate sum, which still may be easier for you to gather than going all the way dark and back light again. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the answer is "No, not really".  There is not much benefit to retaining a particular alignment unless you (a) really like a particular piece of alignment-bound gear, (b) want to preserve your character's character, or (c) prefer the titles that come with that alignment.